# AWS Athena INSERT now throws mismatched input when followed with USING EXTERNAL FUNCTION

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

We have an Athena query that inserts data from one table by selecting it from another, and as part of the insert it uses a Lambda function to add some extra data (H3 hex references) to the table.

This was working fine until a couple of weeks ago, and suddenly it has stopped with an error:

> line 2:37: mismatched input 'USING'. Expecting: '(',

The full query:

```
INSERT INTO orc_data_table
USING EXTERNAL FUNCTION geo_to_h3_address(lat DOUBLE, lng DOUBLE, res INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LAMBDA 'h3-athena-udf-handler'
SELECT
  id,
  datafield1,
  datafield2,
  geo_to_h3_address(cast(latitude as double), cast(longitude as double), 10) hex10,
  geo_to_h3_address(cast(latitude as double), cast(longitude as double), 11) hex11,
  geo_to_h3_address(cast(latitude as double), cast(longitude as double), 12) hex12,
  year(date(from_unixtime(CAST(location_at as integer)))) as year,
  month(date(from_unixtime(CAST(location_at as integer)))) as month,
  day(date(from_unixtime(CAST(location_at as integer)))) as day,
  concat(CAST(CAST(floor(CAST(longitude AS double)) AS integer) AS varchar), '.', CAST(CAST(floor(CAST(latitude AS double)) AS integer) AS varchar)) AS geohash
FROM src_csv_table
WHERE day(date(from_unixtime(CAST(location_at as integer)))) = 23
AND month(date(from_unixtime(cast(location_at AS integer)))) = 3
AND year(date(from_unixtime(cast(location_at AS integer)))) = 2023
```

Can anyone see why this would not be valid, especially as it has been working fine?  Any help is very much appreciated.